# Postgres - Count cross more tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

is there a way to do some calculation like this in SQL?

I have 3 tables

Message

| ID | Text |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | First question round |
| 2 | Second question round |

Message Slide

| ID | MessageID | Question |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | How do you feel? |
| 2 | 1 | Where do you work? |
| 3 | 2 | Skiing or swimming? |

Message audience

| ID | MessageID | UserID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | 2 |

I need to know how many slides (questions) should I have answered.

The calculation should be: the sum of (each audience * message slide);

First message has 2 slides/question, so it is:
2 (questions) * 3 (users) = 6

Second message has 1 slide / question, so it is:
1 (question) * 2 (users) = 2

Result I'm looking for is 6 + 2 = 8;

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=57f1afe704e181cc7d4c7be6247e0686)

Simply join all data sets and count the records?

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM message m
JOIN slide s ON s."MessageID" = m."ID"
JOIN audience a ON a."MessageID" = m."ID"
```

To count the record number for each message separately you need to group by the message ID, which gives exactly what you are expecting: 6 and 2:

```
SELECT
    m."ID",
    COUNT(*)
FROM message m
JOIN slide s ON s."MessageID" = m."ID"
JOIN audience a ON a."MessageID" = m."ID"
GROUP BY m."ID"
```